# How to partially specialize a struct template for non-member & member function pointer

Tags: c++

I'm doing some template metaprogramming involving function pointers. Because the function types for non-member and member function pointers are different, I'm trying to specialize between the two. Furthermore, I want the pointer to the function to be provided as a non-type template argument instead of a parameter to a function in the struct. So far here's what I have attempted:

```cpp
template <typename T, T>
struct register_method;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct register_method<R(Args...), R (*method)(Args...)>
{
    static R invoke(Args&&... params)
    {
        return (*method)(std::forward<Args>(params)...);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
struct register_method<R(Args...), R (T::*method)(Args...)>
{
    static R invoke(T* instance, Args&&... params)
    {
        return (instance->*method)(std::forward<Args>(params)...);
    }
};
```

However this fails to compile (here's just the first error):

```
prog.cc:14:48: error: 'Args' does not refer to a value
struct register_method<R(Args...), R (*method)(Args...)>
                                               ^
prog.cc:13:35: note: declared here
template <typename R, typename... Args>
                                  ^
```

I'm not really sure what it is trying to tell me. My goal is to utilize these objects like so:

```cpp
void the_func(float val)
{
    std::cout << "the_func called: " << val << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    register_method<decltype(&the_func), &the_func>::invoke(50.f);
}
```

How can I get this working? If there's an opportunity to simplify, that would be great too (for example, if I can get away with just passing the function pointer to the template instead of also doing a `decltype`, which should reduce boilerplate.

EDIT: Also want to add that the reason I need separate specializations for non-member and member functions extend beyond just the function types being different. There is static state between the two that is different, due to the business rules I attach to the different function types. I have omitted those details here to keep the question simple.

Comment: Not sure what your use case is but this looks like you are trying to make your own [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke).  Which version of C++ are you using?

Comment: @NathanOliver I am using C++17 with Clang. While my intent is different, my interface will surely resemble that of `std::invoke`. However I amended my question with the disclaimer that there is more business logic attached to each specialization not shown here, so I am not just creating a simple call wrapper, although that is the end goal.

Comment: If you use C++17, you could use `template <auto method> struct register_method`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Could you provide a more complete example in the form of an answer? I completely forgot about `auto` in templates, that might be what I need, although I'm still worried about the other requirement: Being able to split the return type and the arguments. I'm not sure how you accomplish this in the `auto` case.

Comment: Unrelated to the error your question is asking, but your perfect forwarding doesn't work.  `Args` in the signature of your `invoke` members isn't being used in a deduced context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can fix the code:

```
template <typename T, T>
struct register_method;

template <typename R, typename... Args, R (*method)(Args...)>
struct register_method<R (*)(Args...), method>
{
    template <typename ...P>
    static R invoke(P &&... params)
    {
        return (*method)(std::forward<P>(params)...);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args, R (T::*method)(Args...)>
struct register_method<R (T::*)(Args...), method>
{
    template <typename ...P>
    static R invoke(T *instance, P &&... params)
    {
        return (instance->*method)(std::forward<P>(params)...);
    }
};
```

Note that you have to introduce a separate parameter pack for the forwarding references to work, since they only work if the template parameter is being deduced.

---

And here is an alternative solution using C++17 `auto` template parameters:

```
template <auto method>
struct register_method;

template <typename R, typename... Args, R (*method)(Args...)>
struct register_method<method>
{
    template <typename ...P>
    static R invoke(P &&... params)
    {
        return (*method)(std::forward<P>(params)...);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args, R (T::*method)(Args...)>
struct register_method<method>
{
    template <typename ...P>
    static R invoke(T *instance, P &&... params)
    {
        return (instance->*method)(std::forward<P>(params)...);
    }
};
```

Comment: The version of the C++17 solution you had previously deleted was better than this. Instead of declaring `P` again for `invoke()`, I simply use `Args&&... params` and it works without declaring template arguments for the static function

Comment: @void.pointer It doesn't really work. Let's say you have `void foo(int)`. Then `Args` is `int`, and `Args&&... params` is `int &&params`. So passing an lvalue, e.g. `int x = 1; ...::invoke(x);` is not going to work.

Comment: I believe `Args&&...` represents a universal reference, So it would really come in as `int& params`, I think.

Comment: @void.pointer [Nah, it doesn't work.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16653b0d893fae50) It would become `int &params`, if `Args` somehow was `int &`. But `Args` is already `int`. For a reference to be forwarding (aka universal), you have to let the compiler deduce the type of the parameter.

Comment: You are right. Because my example is a bit misleading, I thought it was deducing Args again but it is not, as you state. Forwarding references only apply to function template arguments. Thanks for the detail-oriented solution.

Answer (score 1):

Specialization should look like

```
template <typename T, T>
struct register_method;

template <typename R, typename... Args, R (*method)(Args...)>
struct register_method<R (*)(Args...), method>
{
    static R invoke(Args... params)
    {
        return (*method)(std::forward<Args>(params)...);
    }
};

template <typename C, typename R, typename... Args, C (T::*method)(Args...)>
struct register_method<R (C::*)(Args...), method>
{
    static R invoke(T* instance, Args... params)
    {
        return (instance->*method)(std::forward<Args>(params)...);
    }
};
```

Comment: It's an interesting use of `forward`, took me a second to process.

Comment: Since `Args` is being passed by value, can't you just use `move`?

Comment: @NathanOliver Not necessarily by value, `Args` can contain references.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh yeah.  Thanks.